# MySQL Delete do not rollback

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, rollback

```
Delete from test.employee where employee_id = 2002;
```

> 1 row(s) affected

```
rollback;
```

> 0 row(s) affected

**I don't know why I can't rollback the data value that I deleted, please help, thanks**

Comment: To use rollback you have to begin transaction first. Then you can rollback or commit it

Comment: Thank you @zolty13

Answer (score 0):

a) `test.employee` might not be innodb. Check with `show create table test.employee`.
b) You have [autocommit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) enabled (it is the default).

So you can ensure its `innodb`, `set autocommit=0` or `start transaction`, after this, you'll have transactions.

Comment: Thank you @danblack

Answer (score 0):

If you have `autocommit` enabled, then every SQL statement implicitly starts and commits its own transaction.

By the time you run `rollback` it's too late, it's already committed.

If you `start transaction` explicitly, then it won't automatically commit. But once you commit that transaction, the autocommit behavior resumes.

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin